# How to insert number every nth letter in a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, encryption

I'm writing a program to encrypt a string input. I have a random number generator, and some code that converts the random number into a letter. How would I go about inserting this letter after every say, 3rd letter? I.e. String before: abcdef , String after: abcldefk.

Code for the random number generator if it helps:

```
Letter = random.randrange(1,26) 

print chr(Letter + ord('A'))
```

Comment: (it is worth saying that this will probably not be a _secure_ type of encryption) But if you're doing it for fun or to learn: Go for it :)

Comment: Oh, this is only part of the process, I have a lot more to do :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `str.join`, `enumerate` with a start index equal to 1 and modulo:

```
print("".join([x if i % 3 else x + random_letter for i, x in enumerate(s,1)]))
```

If you just want to insert a random letter, you can use `string.ascii_letters` and `random.choice`:

```
from random import choice
from string import ascii_letters

s = "abcdef"
print("".join([x if i % 3 else x + choice(ascii_letters) for i, x in enumerate(s,1)])

abcQdefN
```

Comment: Was just about to hit post on an identical approach. +1 for shortest approach I believe.

Comment: @Elizion,  thanks, I am sure there are numerous ways, this just seemed easy.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if i % 3 == 0`?

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by Padraic's answer and wanted to add a little bit more.

```
import random
Letter = random.randrange(1,26) 

def encrypt_string(string, n):
    return ("".join([x if i % n else chr(Letter + ord('A')) for i, x in enumerate(string)]))
```

Here is a string "encryption" (using it loosely) method for every 'nth' letter.

Results (Answers may vary due to random):

```
print(encrypt_string("0123456789", 2)) # Every other letter
M1M3M5M7M9

print(encrypt_string("0123456789", 3)) # Every third letter
D12D45D78D
```

I hope this helped.